# How to bookmark all open tabs in Opera 30 as a folder?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, opera

How do I bookmark all open tabs (in the current window) in Opera 30 (e.g. as a folder)? There doesn't seem to be such an option in the vanilla installation of Opera...

P.S. Add-on solutions are accepted.

Comment: Click on the Bookmarks panel. Right click on the folder of your choice. Click on "Bookmark All Open Pages."

Comment: @Jatin: I think you're referring to the old Opera (Presto). This does not apply for the newer Opera (Blink).

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter: Yes, you're correct, this is about the new Opera which uses Blink, not the old (Presto-based) Opera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that I've found an Opera extension that does what I want - bookmarking all open tabs as a folder (and also offers the option to export all bookmarks as an .html), but its extension permissions are too much if you're even a bit paranoid, so stay away from it if you're concerned about your privacy:

https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/v7-bookmarks/

I've tested it with Opera 30 and Opera 31.0 and it works fine.

P.S. Session Buddy (as mentioned by @
BlueBerry - Vignesh4303) is also an option, but it's more of a session manager and not a bookmarks manager. If you just need a list of all open URIs and don't like to bother saving them as bookmarks or as a browser session, you may want to check the following Opera extensions: *CopyURLs* or *Copy URL + Title* and *Bulk URL Opener*.

Comment: Thanks, I like the CopyURLs and Bulk URL Opener since this approach allows me to copy a subset of the addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Opera 30, but in 33 there's an option in the context menu of the tabs - "Save tabs as Speed Dial folder" - and I don't think it's a new feature. If it's there, just click it, then go to Bookmarks, navigate to the Speed Dial folder and drag the new folder elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Thanks for the vanilla solution (i.e. one that doesn't involve the use of Opera / Chrome extensions)! Still, Opera shouldn't have made it so lame - they should have just added the option **Bookmark All Open Pages (as folder)** rather than forcing us to move those 'Speed Dial folders' around since that's a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

You Could click on the **Bookmarks panel**. `Right click` on the folder of your choice. Click on **Bookmark All Open Pages**

Additionally you could try on [Session Buddy](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/),which could help you to install google chrome extensions to opera browser

Now add session buddy from over [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) and manage bookmarks.

Comment: I can't see the Bookmarks panel... However, `opera://bookmarks/` opens just fine, but right-clicking on a newly-created folder there doesn't offer me the option to **Bookmark All Open Pages**.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the [Copy URLs](https://addons.opera.com/de/extensions/details/copy-urls-2/?display=en) extension for opera
- Use *open URLs* in second program.
- Use external program to maintain all your bookmarks.

Opera isn't designed for bookmarks, however you can save sessions and “attach” a session name to a bookmark with *Save Session V7.*

Comment: Please be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state, and confirming this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post.